there is motion trail effect in my drag and drop prefab
so i want to drag and drop prefab in unity. apparently, there is a motion trail effect when the prefab is being dragged just like the gif below. and i also put the code that i tried, and i still dont know how to fix it. any solution?

void Start()
    {
        // Store the original position of the prefab
        originalPosition = transform.position;

        // Get the ProductPrefabDestructor component attached to the spawn point
        prefabDestructor = reactionProductPoint.GetComponent<ProductPrefabDestructor>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            Vector3 worldPosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, worldPosition + offset, Time.deltaTime * 10f);
        }
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            isDragging = true;
            Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
            mousePosition.z = 10; // Distance from the camera
            offset = transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        }
    }

    private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition()
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition.z = 10; // Distance from the camera
        return Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
    }

    void OnMouseUp()
    {
        if (isDragging)
        {
            isDragging = false;
            if (isOverlapping && overlappingCollider != null)
            {
                // Destroy the previously spawned product prefab
                prefabDestructor.DestroySpawnedProductPrefab();
                
                // Spawn prefab based on overlapping collider
                SpawnProductPrefab(overlappingCollider);
            }
            // Reset the position of the dragged prefab to its original position
            transform.position = originalPosition;
        }
    }


How often is OnMouseUp triggered? It might trigger every tick and flip-flop the isDragging field from true to false and causing to spawn a lot of prefabs.

I feel like a lot of drag-related issues can be solved by using unity's built-in drag handler interfaces, most importantly IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler. Maybe try using these instead. If nothing else it'll make everything more readable, and may solve any bool flip-flopping like @ValerijDobler mentions.
